# Symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I made a simple C++ project using Qt, the goal is to extract some connected components from images and save them into proper folders.

I only use one .cpp file and opencv to do so.

But when I run my program I get this error:  `Symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi`

To be honest I don't understand what's going on. I tried to look on some thread where people had the same issue but nothing worked so far.

I checked with `ldd -d -r ./ExctractCC` and everything seems to be ok:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa23c4000)    
libopencv_core.so.2.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.2.4 (0x00007f3c5522c000)   
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 (0x00007f3c54fe3000)     
libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 (0x00007f3c54b57000)     
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3c547d5000)     
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3c544cc000)   
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f3c542b5000)   
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3c53eeb000)   
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f3c53cd1000)   
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3c53ab3000)   
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3c538ab000)    
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f3c53637000)    
libtbb.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2 (0x00007f3c533f9000)   
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007f3c531a0000)     
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f3c52f7b000)   
libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f3c52d06000)     
libjasper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1 (0x00007f3c52ab1000)     
libIlmImf-2_2.so.22 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf-2_2.so.22 (0x00007f3c525e3000)   
libHalf.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so.12 (0x00007f3c5239f000)   
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c51d54000)   
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c51a9f000)   
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c5184b000)   
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c5153a000)     
libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c51336000)     
libgdkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdkglext-x11-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c510d1000)     
libdc1394.so.22 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.22 (0x00007f3c50e5b000)   
libv4l1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l1.so.0 (0x00007f3c50c55000)     
libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f3c4f828000)  
libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat-ffmpeg.so.56 (0x00007f3c4f42a000)     
libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil-ffmpeg.so.54 (0x00007f3c4f1bb000)     
libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale-ffmpeg.so.3 (0x00007f3c4ef2b000)     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b4ab2ea000)    
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f3c4ed02000)   
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f3c4eafe000)     
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f3c4e8fb000)   
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f3c4e6f4000)     
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f3c4e4f0000)   
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f3c4e2c1000)   
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f3c4e0af000)     
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f3c4deab000)   
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f3c4dca5000)     
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f3c4daa3000)   
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f3c4d768000)   
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f3c4d54f000)   
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f3c4d34a000)     
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f3c4d127000)   
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f3c4cf21000)   
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f3c4cd12000)   
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3c4cb0d000)     
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f3c4c8eb000)     
libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 (0x00007f3c4c6dc000)  
libIex-2_2.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex-2_2.so.12 (0x00007f3c4c4be000)     
libIlmThread-2_2.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread-2_2.so.12 (0x00007f3c4c2b7000)     
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4c0b2000)   
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4bea5000)     
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4bc80000)   
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f3c4b96b000)   
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4b749000)     
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4b3c1000)   
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4b1aa000)     
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4af5e000)   
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f3c4ad1b000)     
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f3c4ab10000)   
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f3c4a90d000)     
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f3c4a6fc000)     
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f3c4a4f1000)     
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f3c4a2e7000)   
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f3c4a0e4000)     
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f3c49edb000)   
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f3c49c6b000)     
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f3c499fb000)   
libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 (0x00007f3c497e2000)   
libpangox-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangox-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c495c2000)     
libraw1394.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw1394.so.11 (0x00007f3c493b2000)     
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c4919a000)   
libv4l2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l2.so.0 (0x00007f3c48f8c000)     
libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample-ffmpeg.so.1 (0x00007f3c48d6e000)   
libva.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.1 (0x00007f3c48b52000)     
libzvbi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 (0x00007f3c488c7000)     
libxvidcore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 (0x00007f3c485b2000)     
libx265.so.79 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.79 (0x00007f3c47993000)   
libx264.so.148 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.148 (0x00007f3c475ef000)     
libwebp.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5 (0x00007f3c47392000)     
libwavpack.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwavpack.so.1 (0x00007f3c47169000)   
libvpx.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.3 (0x00007f3c46d45000)   
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f3c46a9b000)   
libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f3c4686f000)     
libtwolame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtwolame.so.0 (0x00007f3c4664c000)   
libtheoraenc.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 (0x00007f3c4640c000)   
libtheoradec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so.1 (0x00007f3c461f2000)   
libspeex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex.so.1 (0x00007f3c45fd9000)   
libsnappy.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1 (0x00007f3c45dd0000)     
libshine.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshine.so.3 (0x00007f3c45bc3000)   
libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libschroedinger-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f3c458ee000)     
libopus.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so.0 (0x00007f3c456a3000)     
libopenjpeg.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjpeg.so.5 (0x00007f3c45480000)     
libmp3lame.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 (0x00007f3c4520b000)   
libgsm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm.so.1 (0x00007f3c44ffc000)   
libcrystalhd.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrystalhd.so.3 (0x00007f3c44de1000)   
libssh-gcrypt.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh-gcrypt.so.4 (0x00007f3c44b97000)     
librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007f3c4497b000)     
libmodplug.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmodplug.so.1 (0x00007f3c445f0000)   
libgme.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgme.so.0 (0x00007f3c443a1000)   
libbluray.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluray.so.1 (0x00007f3c44158000)     
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f3c43e28000)   
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f3c43c17000)   
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f3c43a13000)   
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f3c4380c000)   
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f3c43562000)     
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f3c432b9000)     
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f3c430b5000)   
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f3c42eab000)     
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f3c42c88000)   
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f3c42a6d000)     
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f3c4280f000)     
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f3c42605000)     
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f3c4239c000)     
libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f3c4237b000)     
libv4lconvert.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4lconvert.so.0 (0x00007f3c42101000)     
libsoxr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr.so.0 (0x00007f3c41e9c000)     
libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f3c41c90000)     
libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f3c41a87000)   
liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f3c41806000)   
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f3c41525000)   
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f3c412da000)   
libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f3c410a7000)   
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f3c40e71000)     
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f3c40bf0000)     
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f3c40835000)     
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f3c405d0000)   
libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007f3c4039d000)     
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f3c4018a000)   
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f3c3ff64000)   
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f3c3fd5c000)     
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f3c3fb53000)     
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f3c3f939000)   
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f3c3f717000)     
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f3c3f502000)   
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f3c3f230000)     
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f3c3f000000)     
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f3c3edfc000)   
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f3c3ebf1000)   
libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f3c3e85c000)     
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f3c3e657000)     
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f3c3e453000)     
libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f3c3c99b000) 
undefined symbol:
_ZN2cv7imwriteERKSsRKNS_11_InputArrayERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE   (./ExctractCC) undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi    (./ExctractCC)
```

Except for the two undefined symbol at the end.
It seems to be linked with opencv as I can read Imread, but reinstall opencv 2.4 didn't work.

I got the same error with another project which used to work perfectly before I upgrade my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, the other change I made is to download g++4.9.
I'm not sure if there is a missing library I should install, a compiler issue or something else.
If someone have a hint?

Edit: Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <main.h>
#include <processImage.h>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int maxHeight = 2500;
    int normHeight = 2000;

    int rectangleWidth = round((float)normHeight/200.0);

    std::string list_images_train="data/list_images_train";
    if(rectangleWidth <3)
    {
        rectangleWidth = 3;
    }
        //int numLines = countNumberOfLinesInFIle(list_images_train);

    std::vector<std::string> filenames;

     std::ifstream fid1(list_images_train.c_str(), std::ios::in);
     std::string name;

     int x=1;
     while(std::getline(fid1,name))
     {
         filenames.push_back(name);
         x+=1;
     }
    fid1.close();

    int n=filenames.size();

    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        std::string folder="/home/kamel/TRAVAIL/Romain/build-ExctractCC-Desktop-Debug/"+filenames[x];
        int statut=mkdir(folder.c_str(),S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
        std::string imageName="data/"+ filenames[x]+".png";
        std::string gtFile="data/"+ filenames[x] + ".gt";
//The error occurs here:
        cv::Mat imgTest=(cv::imread(imageName.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)); 
        double min,max;
        imgTest.convertTo(imgTest,CV_64F);
        cv::minMaxLoc(imgTest,&min,&max);
        imgTest=(255*((imgTest - min)/(max-min)));
        imgTest.convertTo(imgTest,CV_8U);


        int height=imgTest.rows;
        int width=imgTest.cols;

        int evaluate=1;
        if (gtFile.empty())
        {
            evaluate=0;
        }
        double ratio1= (float)maxHeight/ (float)height;
        cv::resize(imgTest,imgTest,cv::Size(),ratio1,ratio1,cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);
        height=imgTest.rows;
        width=imgTest.cols;
        cv::Mat binImg;
        (cv::GaussianBlur(imgTest,imgTest,cv::Size(7,7),0,0));
        imgTest.convertTo(imgTest,CV_8U);
        double thrsh= cv::threshold(imgTest,binImg,0,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV |CV_THRESH_OTSU);
         std::vector<std::string> vars;
         boost::split(vars,imageName, boost::is_any_of("/"),boost::token_compress_on);
        cv::Mat binImg0= binImg.clone();

        double ratio2= float(normHeight)/float(height);

        if(imgTest.cols==0){
            std::cout<<"Error reading file"<<std::endl;
        }
        cv::resize(imgTest,imgTest,cv::Size(),ratio2,ratio2,cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);
        height=binImg.rows;
        width=binImg.cols;

        binImg/=255;
        cv::resize(binImg,binImg,cv::Size(),ratio2,ratio2,cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);

        cv::Mat imgcontour=binImg.clone();
        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > CC;
        cv::findContours(imgcontour, CC,hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0,0));

        int sizeCC=CC.size();

        for(int i=0;i<sizeCC;i++)
        {
            cv::Mat pointsf;
            cv::Mat(CC[i]).convertTo(pointsf, CV_32F);
            cv::Rect box=cv::boundingRect(pointsf);
            cv::Mat tmpimg=binImg.colRange(box.x,box.x+box.width).rowRange(box.y,box.y + box.height);
            std::ostringstream name;
            name << folder << "/CC"<<i << ".png";
            cv::imwrite(name.str(),tmpimg);
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: use c++filt to demangle function name - _ZN2cv6imreadERKSsi is `cv::imread(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)`

Comment: Looks like you upgrade library and signature of that method was changed. You need to rebuild your app. It is not missing library - it is upgrade and new library is incompatible.

Comment: @Slava> I used c++filt to demangle function name and the undefined symbole are related to `imwrite()` and `imread()` function.
I tried to rebuild everything: I rebuild my project, and I reinstalled opencv following this method: https://gist.github.com/jayant-yadav/809723151f2f72a93b2ee1040c337427 to be sure it's compatible with Ubuntu 16.04. But I still get the same issue. I got the error as soon as I use `Imread()`

@eyllanesc > I'll edit my post to add my code.

Comment: change `cv::Mat imgTest=(cv::imread(imageName.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));` to `cv::Mat imgTest=cv::imread(imageName.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);`

Comment: If your build succeeded and you have missing symbols on runtime then you link against one set of libraries and run against another. If you build and run on the same machine then your build environment is messed up. Check which libraries you link against and validate that the same libraries are loaded at runtime (using ldd utility) and fix your environment accordingly.

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried your suggestion but I still have an error.

Comment: @Slava Indeed I run and build from the same machine. Youre probably right , my build environment must be messed up. I will check this.

Comment: Hi @RomainMartin, how are you building the code?? Try `g++ <fileName.cpp> -o <fileName> \`pkg-cconfig --cflags --libs opencv\``. It should work.

Comment: @Akhilesh I'm building the code using Qt, I tried you're code but nothing happened. Maybe I did something wrong?
I went to the directory were my code is and run your command replacing fileName by the name of my main file.

Comment: @Slava You were right, when I run ldd on my file the opencv's libraries loaded at runtime aren't the same I specified in my pro file. But I don't know how to force my project to run the right libraries.

Comment: @RomainMartin, sorry for the typo in `g++ <fileName.cpp> -o <fileName> \`pkg-cconfig --cflags --libs opencv\``, actually it is `g++ <fileName.cpp> -o <fileName> \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\``. It added extra `c` in `pkg-config`. I hope you tried the correct if you knew. If not tried yet, then try once. If nothing happens then just run `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` command on terminal and add the result in the comment. It should display your linking library path.

Comment: @RomainMartin "But I don't know how to force my project to run the right libraries." Just set LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable accordingly (path to lib you need comes before anything else).

Comment: @Akhilesh Sorry it's my fault I should have read the line properly. But I still got an error: the compiler says that it can't find main.h, the header of my main function. I checked and it's present in my project's folder, right after main.cpp, no mixed-case nor speacial characters used. I can't understand why it's not finding it. I tried to had the -I option specifying the path where my header is located bu nothing change. I'll look after for a solution.

Comment: @Slava I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly, now when I check with `ldd` the opencv library loaded are the same as the ones included in my .pro file.
However I still get the same error. I noticed that the folder containing my .so path seems to contain different versions of them. For example: libopencv_core.so libopencv_core.so.2.4 and libopencv_core.so.2.4.13. I don't know what it supposed to means?
I told my programme to use libopencv_core.so in my .pro file (as it's the only one I can select between the different versions using Qt) but when I check with ldd, libopencv_core.so.2.4 is used.

Comment: The `imwrite()` function is defined in the `imgcodecs` library (maybe `img_codecs` on OpenCV 2.x) so you need to add that to your linker... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276430/2836621