# OpenCV imwrite function causes 'undefined symbol'

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm working on a piece of software that consists of some core C++ code with python bindings. The C++ code uses a lot of OpenCV already but now I'm trying to save an image somewhere in between and I can't seem to use the `imwrite` function. Adding it in the main.cpp and compiling in eclipse with the 'Default' build works, but in order to use it with the existing Python code, I need to build with CMake. This again compiles fine, but when I call the code from my Python class I get this error:

```
ImportError: /.../pythonCPP.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv7imwriteERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE
```

I searched for this and from what I could gather, this often seems to stem from some sort of linking problem. I don't know where to start looking or adding any flags in the CMake file though. I'm using OpenCV 3.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

This is the corresponding CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project("blah")

#----------------------------CMAKE & GLOBAL PROPERTIES-------------------------#
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

###============= C++11 support====================================
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if (COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -g0 -s -std=c++11")
elseif (COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -g0 -s -std=c++0x")
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif ()
#=================================================================
# PYTHON option

set(PYTHON_OPTIONS "2.X" "3.X")
set(PYTHON_DESIRED_VERSION "3.X" CACHE STRING "Choose which python version to use, options are: ${PYTHON_OPTIONS}.")
set_property(CACHE PYTHON_DESIRED_VERSION PROPERTY STRINGS ${PYTHON_OPTIONS})


#=============== Find Packages
find_package(OpenCV 3 COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc REQUIRED)
message("Open CV version is ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
include("DetectPython")
if (${PYTHON_DESIRED_VERSION} STREQUAL "2.X")
    set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS ${PYTHON2_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON2_VERSION_MINOR})
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python-py${PYTHON2_VERSION_MAJOR}${PYTHON2_VERSION_MINOR} REQUIRED)
else ()
    set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS ${PYTHON3_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PYTHON3_VERSION_MINOR})
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python-py${PYTHON3_VERSION_MAJOR}${PYTHON3_VERSION_MINOR} REQUIRED)
endif ()

#========pick python stuff========================================
if (${PYTHON_DESIRED_VERSION} STREQUAL "2.X")
    SET(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR} ${PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR2} ${PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(PYTHON_LIBRARIES ${PYTHON2_LIBRARY})
    SET(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE ${PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE})
    SET(PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH ${PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH})
    SET(ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME py2)
else ()
    SET(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR} ${PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR2} ${PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    SET(PYTHON_LIBRARIES ${PYTHON3_LIBRARY})
    SET(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE ${PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE})
    SET(PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH ${PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH})
    SET(ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME py3)
endif ()

file(GLOB project_sources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${project_sources} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/pyboostcvconverter/pyboostcvconverter.hpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
        ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
        )

#---------------------------   INSTALLATION    -----------------------------------------------------
#-get proper extension for python binary shared object on this platform
execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -c "import distutils.sysconfig; print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('SO'))"
        RESULT_VARIABLE PYTHON_${PROJECT_NAME}_PY_PROCESS
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${PROJECT_NAME}_PY_SUFFIX
        OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME ${ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_NAME}  # prevent name conflict for python2/3 outputs
        PREFIX ""
        OUTPUT_NAME py
        SUFFIX ${${PROJECT_NAME}_PY_SUFFIX})

if (MSVC AND NOT PYTHON_DEBUG_LIBRARIES)
    set(PYTHON_INSTALL_CONFIGURATIONS CONFIGURATIONS Release)
else ()
    set(PYTHON_INSTALL_CONFIGURATIONS "")
endif ()

if (WIN32)
    set(PYTHON_INSTALL_ARCHIVE "")
else ()
    set(PYTHON_INSTALL_ARCHIVE ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH} COMPONENT python)
endif ()

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${PYTHON_INSTALL_CONFIGURATIONS}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH} COMPONENT python
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH} COMPONENT python
        ${PYTHON_INSTALL_ARCHIVE}
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not best on **cmake**, but you appear to have failed to link the `imwrite()` function.

I'm on a Mac so this will be different if you are elsewhere, but if you look in the OpenCV libraries directory, specifically in `libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib` like this:

```
nm -gUP  libopencv_imgcodecs.dylib | grep -i write
```

You will see something like:

```
__ZN2cv7imwriteERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNSt3__16vector...
```

That means that `imgcodecs` provides the function you need.

I am, I hope (thanks to @Ptaq666), reliably informed that the best way of adding this library will be to use:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
```

followed by:

```
target_link_libraries(<as you already have> ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

---

**Original suggestion**

That means that `imgcodecs` provides the function you need, so I think you need to add that into this line in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc REQUIRED)
```

I guess that will be something like:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc imgcodecs REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Good answer, however I would recommend using just `find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)` and then `target_link_libraries(xxx yyy ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}`. It is quite unlikely that someone uses OpenCV without `imgcodecs` modules.

Comment: @Ptaq666 Thank you for the advice - I have edited my code and hope it is now improved. Thanks again.